# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option error in my APEX SQL SCRIPT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, create-table, alter-table

Can you tell me where is that error happening?

ERROR FULL TEXT:

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option ORA-06512: at 
"SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 626 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", 
line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 612 ORA-06512: 
at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1749
```

````
create table Angajati (
    id_angajat int,
    nume varchar2(30),
    prenume varchar2(50),
    id_functie int,
    id_locatie int,
    telefon varchar2(11),
    data_angajare date,
    salariul int,
    id_manager int
)

create table Clienti (
    id_client int,
    nume_client varchar2(30),
    prenume_client varchar2(50),
    telefon varchar2(11),
    id_angajati int
)

create table Locatii (
    id_locatie int,
    adresa varchar2(500),
    oras varchar2(50),
    judet varchar2(50),
    cod_postal int
)

create table Functii (
    id_functie int,
    denumire_functie varchar2(50),
    salariu_min int,
    salariu_max int
)

create table Comenzi (
    id_comanda int,
    id_angajat int 
)

--ALTER
--Restrictii pentru tabela Angajati
alter table Angajati add constraint pk_id primary key (id_angajat)
alter table Angajati add constraint fk_func foreign key (id_functie) references Functii(id_functie)
alter table Angajati add constraint fk_loc foreign key (id_locatie) references Locatii(id_locatie)
alter table Angajati add constraint uq_tel unique (telefon)

--Restritii pentru tabela Clienti
alter table Clienti add constraint pk_id primary key (id_client)
alter table Clienti add constraint uq_tel unique (telefon)
alter table Clienti add constraint fk_ang foreign key (id_angajat) references Angajati(id_angajat)

--Restrictii pentru tabela Locatii
alter table Locatii add constraint pk_id primary key (id_locatie)
alter table Locatii add constraint uq_adresa unique (adresa)

--Restrictii pentru tabela Functii
alter table Functii add constraint pk_id primary key (id_functie)

--DROP
drop table Comenzie here```

**WHERE IS THE PROBLEM ???**
````

Comment: I would try running each of the statements one at a time to see which one is causing the error. Also, all of your statements are missing a `;` at the end which may be causing the issue if you are trying to run them all in one script.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue with your code is the missing statement terminator: every sql command must be terminated with a `;`.

But there is more. Your code first creates the tables, then adds the constraints (primary keys, foreign keys, unique keys). Things need to be done in a well-defined order: to create a foreign key, you need the primary or unique constraint to be set up already on the parent column. So you would need to reorder the `alter table` statements so that constraints that are involved in foreign key dependencies are created first, before the FKs. Or better yet, you can declare the PK constraints in the `create table` statement.

Finally, you have given the same name to two different constraints:

```
alter table Angajati add constraint uq_tel unique (telefon);
alter table Clienti add constraint uq_tel unique (telefon);
```

This is not possible; a constraint name must be unique in a given schema. You need to give different names to these two objects.

Note that you could very well declare all dependencies as part of the `create table` statements - provided that tables are created in the correct sequence - rather than running multiple `alter table` afterwards.

That would look like:

```
create table Locatii (
    id_locatie int primary key,
    adresa varchar2(500) constraint uq_adresa unique,
    oras varchar2(50),
    judet varchar2(50),
    cod_postal int
);

create table Functii (
    id_functie int primary key,
    denumire_functie varchar2(50),
    salariu_min int,
    salariu_max int
);

create table Comenzi (
    id_comanda int primary key,
    id_angajat int 
);

create table Angajati (
    id_angajat int primary key,
    nume varchar2(30),
    prenume varchar2(50),
    id_functie int constraint fk_func references Functii(id_functie),
    id_locatie int constraint fk_loc references Locatii(id_locatie),
    telefon varchar2(11) constraint uq_angajati_tel unique,
    data_angajare date,
    salariul int,
    id_manager int
);

create table Clienti (
    id_client int primary key,
    nume_client varchar2(30),
    prenume_client varchar2(50),
    telefon varchar2(11) constraint uq_clienti_tel unique,
    id_angajati int constraint fk_ang references Angajati(id_angajat)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=837e48d69bf9326418e36f735cd0c2b6)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this *script* in Oracle Application Express **SQL Workshop**, then you have to highligh & execute one statement by one - you can't run them all at once.

If these were DMLs, you could enclose them into BEGIN-END (and create an anonymous PL/SQL block) which would help. But, with DDL, you have to use dynamic SQL in PL/SQL and that's more pain than gain so I wouldn't recommend it.

So, yes - statement by statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- `foreign keys` are created before `primary/unique` keys.
- invalid name of column is mentioned in one of the `alter table` commands.

By just changing the order of the commands it works correctly.

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25e089a080953916d2b9190ac651b715) with correct schema.